# Campo de la tabla se tome como independiente

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Un saludo, quisiera que me ayudaran ya que que listo los registros de una tabla atraves de una funcion y lo que pasa es que la columna id le he agregado la funcion de que al pulsarla ese valor lo tome un campo de texto y el problema es que al pulsar esta columna todos los id de la tabla se van para el campo de texto y solo necesito el valor que seleccione, esta es la funcion

```
function Listar($columna){
    include("Conexion.php");

    $consulta="SELECT $columna FROM usuario";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($consulta);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>=1){
        while($usuarios=$resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
            $var=$usuarios[$columna];
            echo $var."<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "no hay registros para listar";
    }
```

Y asi lo estoy imprimiendo

```
<td><a href="#" class="name"><?php echo Listar('id_usuario'); ?></a></td>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo pude solucionar imprimiendo los datos de cada usuario independientemente ya que al listarse todos en un mismo `echo` se tomaban como una sola columna, esta fue la forma de solucionarlo                                                                                                                                                  `echo "<tr><td class='name'>".$usuarios['id_usuario']."</td><td>".$usuarios['nombre']."</td><td>".$usuarios['apellido']."</td><td>".$usuarios['telefono']."</td><td>".$usuarios['direccion']."</td><td>".$usuarios['correo']."</td><td>".$usuarios['password']."</td></tr>";`                      [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Asi lo llamo la funcion `<td><a href="#" class="name"><?php echo Listar('id_usuario'); ?></a></td>`

Comment: ¿Cómo se rellena la tabla de valores? Parece que sería con JS en lugar de con PHP. ¿no? Si es así, ¿podrías añadir el código JavaScript relacionado?

Comment: Lo pude solucionar de esta forma  imprimiendo un registro independientemente                                                                                                    **`  echo "<tr><td class='name'>".$usuarios['id_usuario']."</td><td class='name'>".$usuarios['nombre']."</td></tr>";   
  } `** @ Alvaro Montoro gracias

Comment: deberías añadir eso (con una explicación un poco más larga con el porqué) como respuesta y aceptarla. Así si alguien se encuentra con un problema similar, podrá orientarse con tu respuesta. Además, así la gente verá que conseguiste solucionar el problema (y podrías ganar algún puntillo.

Answer (score 0):

En tu función `Listar` precisamente estás recorriendo en el `for` *todos* tus usuarios.

Para solucionarlo (Si he entendido bien tu problemática) no necesitas ninguna función, puedes simplemente llamar a lo que necesitar así:

```
echo $usuarios['id_usuario']
```

Dentro de tu tabla o como lo tengas definido.

Comment: Pero como esta en un archivo diferente por eso lo llamo atraves de una función buscando que todo este modularizado @Miquel Coll

Answer (score 0):

Publicado en un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15195/campo-de-la-tabla-se-tome-como-independiente#comment-25270) por el OP:

> Lo pude solucionar de esta forma imprimiendo un registro independientemente `echo "<tr><td class='name'>".$usuarios['id_usuario']."</td><td class='name'>".$usuarios['nombre']."</td></tr>";  }` @ Alvaro Montoro gracias